# Java: String UTF-8 encoding difference between local app and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, utf-8

I am trying to get a Google App Engine web app to send back UTF-8 encoded text to the browser.
I do this, by writing this:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = "æøå".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

When I do this locally, I get a byte array with 6 bytes back.
When I do this on Google App Engine, I get an array with 12 bytes back. Weird, eh?

Does anyone know why?

I have succeeded in writing UTF-8 encoded text from GAE, by encoding the bytes myself,
and write the raw bytes back. Like this:

```
output.write(new byte[]{(byte)0xc3, (byte)0xa5, (byte) 0xc3, (byte)0xa6, (byte)0xc3, (byte)0xb8 });
```

And this actually works. But, does anyone have an answer to why the String's are encoded differently on GAE, than they are locally?

Note: Encoding the characters via unicode escapes worked - like this:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = "\u00E5\u00F8\u00E6".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: What are the 12 bytes you are getting from GAE?

Comment: The 12 bytes obtained in GAE are (hex values)

    c3 83 c2 a6 c3 83 c2 b8 c3 83 c2 a5


Locally, the 6 bytes are:

    c3 a6 c3 b8 c3 a5

Comment: @Jakob - is there any difference in how you compile the sources? See [here.](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles)

Comment: @McDowell: Yes, actually there is. I'll look into it, and get back.

Comment: I can get a JSP to accept input from a form field, and send it to the server (GAE) as UTF-8. When the server writes the data back to the browser, it is endoded correctly, in UTF-8. But not hardcoded String's inside the app (which I hope I won't need, long term).

Comment: I ended up writing the \u encodings in the code instead, and then it works. It must be a compiler issue - thinking that the Java files were not already UTF-8, and thus double-encoding the strings.

This works
    byte[] utf8Bytes = "\u00E5\u00F8\u00E6".getBytes("UTF-8");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytes you are getting from GAE makes me assume that the source code file with the "æøå" literal is saved as UTF-8, but compiled with a compiler which is expecting the source files to be encoded as ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15 or Cp1252.

If you are building your source code with Ant or Maven, you have to specify the source file encoding in your build.xml or pom.xml.

Comment: I think you are right. I am building the code with Google App Engines scripts / tools. I have looked for switches etc. to change the encoding for the compiler, and did find one, but it did not change anything. 

However, using the \uxxxx codes for the special characters in the code, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have set the content-encoding in your HttpServletResponse before getting a Writer?

Comment: I write the bytes directly to the OutputStream, so the server shouldn't interfere with what I write. Furthermore, the problem arises already before I write the result back. I get 12 bytes out of the String rather than 6 bytes. Already here is the problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. Then indeed your source encoding must be the issue, in eclipse, ant, maven or javac.